# "TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string" getattr() does not call the models from the folder

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, getattr

I am having an issue to understand this given error here. I am adding the source code and the traceback below here. The code is supposed to call necessary models to run the model such as brits, rits, rits_i etc. However, it is not working the way it should. Here is the source code, and the getattr() is close to the end of this source code:

```
import copy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR

import numpy as np

import time
import utils
import models
import argparse
import data_loader
import pandas as pd
import ujson as json

from sklearn import metrics

from ipdb import set_trace

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=1000)
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=32)
parser.add_argument('--model', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--hid_size', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--impute_weight', type=float)
parser.add_argument('--label_weight', type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()


def train(model):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

    data_iter = data_loader.get_loader(batch_size=args.batch_size)

    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        model.train()

        run_loss = 0.0

        for idx, data in enumerate(data_iter):
            data = utils.to_var(data)
            ret = model.run_on_batch(data, optimizer, epoch)

            run_loss += ret['loss'].item()

            print ('\r Progress epoch {}, {:.2f}%, average loss {}'.format(epoch, (idx + 1) * 100.0 / len(data_iter), run_loss / (idx + 1.0)), evaluate(model, data_iter))


def evaluate(model, val_iter):
    model.eval()

    labels = []
    preds = []

    evals = []
    imputations = []

    save_impute = []
    save_label = []

    for idx, data in enumerate(val_iter):
        data = utils.to_var(data)
        ret = model.run_on_batch(data, None)

        # save the imputation results which is used to test the improvement of traditional methods with imputed values
        save_impute.append(ret['imputations'].data.cpu().numpy())
        save_label.append(ret['labels'].data.cpu().numpy())

        pred = ret['predictions'].data.cpu().numpy()
        label = ret['labels'].data.cpu().numpy()
        is_train = ret['is_train'].data.cpu().numpy()

        eval_masks = ret['eval_masks'].data.cpu().numpy()
        eval_ = ret['evals'].data.cpu().numpy()
        imputation = ret['imputations'].data.cpu().numpy()

        evals += eval_[np.where(eval_masks == 1)].tolist()
        imputations += imputation[np.where(eval_masks == 1)].tolist()

        # collect test label & prediction
        pred = pred[np.where(is_train == 0)]
        label = label[np.where(is_train == 0)]

        labels += label.tolist()
        preds += pred.tolist()

    labels = np.asarray(labels).astype('int32')
    preds = np.asarray(preds)

    print ('AUC {}'.format(metrics.roc_auc_score(labels, preds)))

    evals = np.asarray(evals)
    imputations = np.asarray(imputations)

    print ('MAE', np.abs(evals - imputations).mean())

    print ('MRE', np.abs(evals - imputations).sum() / np.abs(evals).sum())

    save_impute = np.concatenate(save_impute, axis=0)
    save_label = np.concatenate(save_label, axis=0)

    np.save('./result/{}_data'.format(args.model), save_impute)
    np.save('./result/{}_label'.format(args.model), save_label)


def run():
    model = getattr(models, args.model).Model(args.hid_size, args.impute_weight, args.label_weight)
    total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
    print('Total params is {}'.format(total_params))

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        model = model.cuda()

    train(model)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Here is the traceback I have:

```
runfile('E:/GAIN Time Series Data Imputation/BRITS-master/main.py', wdir='E:/GAIN Time Series Data Imputation/BRITS-master')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\GAIN Time Series Data Imputation\BRITS-master\main.py", line 120, in <module>
    run()

  File "E:\GAIN Time Series Data Imputation\BRITS-master\main.py", line 109, in run
    model = getattr(models, args.model).Model(args.hid_size, args.impute_weight, args.label_weight)

TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

The necessary models (rits, brits etc.) are under the models folder. But, the function just does not call these models. I will be looking for the resolution.

Comment: So, what is `args.model`, since this error implies that it is not a string, did you do *anything " to debug this? You really must provide a [mcve], there a ton of code here that is probably irrelevant. Furthermore, it relies on command line arguments, which you dont describe how this script is being run

Comment: Script is run by main.py. However, args.model are listed as "rits_i, brits_i, rits, brits, gru_d, m_rnn". These models are under a folder named as "models" and has their own coding file. However, I am not able to call of these models from there to "main.py".

Comment: And, yes most of the code here is irrelevant in the question. I just shared if someone wants to look at it and get familiar with the concept. But, I believe it is better not to share it here.